# Sequential contact number in SFMC journey builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, contact, custom-activity

I have a custom journey builder activity in which it would be helpful to have some Sequential contact number sent in inArguments for each contact that enters the activity (e.g. first contact that enters get number 1, second number 2...).
Is it possible to do this using Data Binding or some other method?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.